# compile java class with jdbc using command prompt

Tags: java, command-line, compilation

I want to compile a java servlet file which includes jdbc using command promp. For this I have used the following command: 
`-cp .;"C:\MyWebProject2\tomcat\lib\servlet-api.jar;C:\MyWebProject2\tomcat\webapps\database\WEB-INF\lib\ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar "DatabaseAccess.java`

Here, my servlet-api.jar file is in the dir `"C:\MyWebProject2\tomcat\lib\"`
and ojdbc.jar file is in the dir `"C:\MyWebProject2\tomcat\webapps\database\WEB-INF\lib\"`

But, I'm recieving output like the following:
 `javac: no source files
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options`

My environment variables are:

`CATALINA_HOME = C:\MyWebProject2\tomcat`
`CLASSPATH = %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%JRE_HOME%\bin;%CATALINA_HOME%\lib`
`JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk`
`JRE_Home = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre`

I am on windows

Answer (score 0):

There should be a space after quote (") and before your java class name.

-cp .;"C:\MyWebProject2\tomcat\lib\servlet-api.jar;C:\MyWebProject2\tomcat\webapps\database\WEB-INF\lib\ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar" DatabaseAccess.java

Comment: thanks, cmd has found the source file. But, I think the classpath for ojdbc driver is not working as Connection type & Statement type reference variables are marked as error having output like following: DatabaseAccess.java:80: error: cannot find symbol if(conn!=null) ^ DatabaseAccess.java:76: error: cannot find symbol stmt.close(); ^ Here is my code: http://pasted.co/f96b96ce